# Is there a way to reuse session in express-session?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

Say I have a login system and at first login, I store the session Id. now when the user login again can I retrieve the session Id, session.destroy() the new session and tell express session to assign the session data from the session store with this retrieved Id to this request?
Thanks
I'm using connect-sqlite3 as session store